# Can AdaBoost be used with multiple measurements?

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

Can Adaboost be used with multiple measurments? If yes, how / why is it working?

Example: let's say I want to predict if it's going to rain=1, or not=-1 and I want to model my prediction based on, let's say, the amount of clouds AND the average atmospheric pressure during a day.

The thing is, I understand for example [what's happening here](http://faculty.utpa.edu/kimd1/class/csci4352-sp16/17_AdaBoostExample.pdf), but I am not able to understand how does Adaboost work when I have "two sets" of $X$s.

Comment: Hi, first, congratulations on your first question. I made small edits to your post, there's no need to salute or thank in posts, we are all here to ask and to answer :)

Comment: Now, about the question itself, a clarification: I think what you mean is multiple measurements of the same observations, right?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your edit suggestions, your welcoming and your guidelines! 

Yes, I believe that "multiple measurements" is a lot better. I will modify the question. Thank you.